# Function even or odd?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, fourier-series

While determining fourier series expansion of following function.

f(x) = $\sqrt{1-\cos x} $

here $f(-x) = f(x)$ so it is even. But

the above function can also be written as 
$f(x) = \sqrt 2\sin(x/2)$

here $f(-x) = -f(x)$
so by that logic it is odd

Can anyone explain where I am wrong.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes: $\sqrt{A^2}=\lvert A\rvert$.

Comment: @ raj Please check my edit/formatting. To take your notation literally, we have $\sqrt 2\sin(x/2)$. But did you mean `\sqrt{2\sin(x/2)}` = $\sqrt{2\sin(x/2)}$?

Comment: No the original notation is correct, and now i understand where i went wrong thank you

Comment: $cos(x)$ is even, so?

Comment: we can also write $ \sqrt{1-\cos x} $ as $\sqrt 2\sin(x/2)$ and sin is odd function because of which I was confused

Answer (score 2):

As said @Bernard in a comment, $\forall A\in\Bbb R,\sqrt{A^2}=|A|$.

Hence $$f(x)=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sin^2(x/2)}=\sqrt{2}|\sin(x/2)|$$ and you can check that $f$ is even.

Comment: $\sqrt{A^2}\,\,$

Comment: Thank you  I understood where i went wrong

Comment: Why $\sqrt(A^2)=|A|$?@paf

Comment: If $A<0$, then $\sqrt{A^2}=-A$ (e.g. $\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$).

Comment: But why you say √$A^2$=|A|?....its is ±A.

Comment: By definition, $|A|=A$ if $A\geq 0$ and $=-A$ if $A<0$.

Comment: If $sqrt{A^2}=|A|$ then the resultant value must be positive? Right .but when we take A<0 ,and square it .then take square root you get A>0.then the how you say square root is inverse of square?

Comment: Square root is the inverse of squaring **only on positive numbers**.

Comment: But in some equation if $x^2$=y we say x =±$\sqrt y$.I.e.$\sqrt{A^2}=±A$

Comment: You're welcome.